# Add two dictionary values in new array . the array values will remains unchanged from its position

Tags: swift

Add two dictionary values in a new array. the array values will remain unchanged from its position. I need to add two dictionary values in a new array. The values added in the array must remain constant at every run.

```
var dictionary1:[String:Int] = ["Mohan":75, "Raghu":82, "John":79] 
var dictionary2:[String:Int] = ["Surya":91, "John":79, "Saranya":92] 
dictionary1.merge(dictionary2){(current, _) in current} 
var arr : [String] = [] 
for (key, value) in dictionary1 { arr.append("(key) (value)") } 
print(dictionary1)
```

Comment: How is the order defined? Please post an example of the expected output with an explanation on how to acquire it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As apple stats, you can use [KeyValuePairs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyvaluepairs) to maintain ordered collection of key-value pairs and don’t require the fast key lookup that the Dictionary type provides.

```
let recordTimes: KeyValuePairs = ["Florence Griffith-Joyner": 10.49,
                                      "Evelyn Ashford": 10.76,
                                      "Evelyn Ashford": 10.79,
                                      "Marlies Gohr": 10.81]
print(recordTimes.first!)
// Prints "("Florence Griffith-Joyner", 10.49)"
```

Check if it is helpful in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use **`append(contentsOf:)`** to add the contents of `dictionary1` and `dictionary2` to `arr`. Use **`map(_:)`** to format the key-value pairs while adding to the `array`.

```
let dictionary1 = ["Mohan":75, "Raghu":82, "John":79]
let dictionary2 = ["Surya":91, "John":79, "Saranya":92]

var arr = [String]()
arr.append(contentsOf: dictionary1.map({"\($0.key) \($0.value)"}))
arr.append(contentsOf: dictionary2.map({"\($0.key) \($0.value)"}))

print(arr) //["Mohan 75", "John 79", "Raghu 82", "Surya 91", "John 79", "Saranya 92"]
```

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered collections. It won't guarantee the same index. The question is about how to keep the index unchanged.